# python error: argument must be a string or a number, not function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
x = np.arange(0, 1.1, h) #point in space
t = np.arange(0, 1.1, k) #point in time
#nodes in matrix form
m = len(x)
n = len(t)
T = np.zeros((m,n))

def ft0 (x):
f = lambda x: math.sin(math.pi*x)# Initial Condition at t=0
return f

for i in range (m-1):
   T[0][i] = ft0[i]
```

When I run the code I get:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
>   'function'

I've been searching through the web for solution but I don't really understand the error.

Comment: Who is `h`,`k`? Also you call the function `ft0` wrong, it should be `ft0(i)`

Comment: Do you also get a line number with that error? Provide the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple issues in the code.

1. `h`, `k` are not defined in the code that you supplied, I assumed them both to be 0.1
2. As I mentioned in the comment, you should call the function as `ft0(i)` and not the way you did.
3. You return the `lambda` function you defined rather than the result, so you should change it to `...return f(x)` rather than `...return f` which cause the mentioned error.

You can see the above in the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def ft0(x):
    f = lambda x: math.sin(math.pi*x)# Initial Condition at t=0
    return f(x)

h=0.1
k=0.1

x = np.arange(0, 1.1, h) #point in space
t = np.arange(0, 1.1, k) #point in time

#nodes in matrix form
#nodes in matrix form
m = len(x)
n = len(t)
T = np.zeros((m,n))

for i in range(m-1):
   T[i][0] = ft0(i)

print(T)
```

**Note**

1. You only assign to the first `column`, you should probably use double for loop
2. In the case of `lambda` inside a function like what you did is unnecessary, you could just use the `lambda` as a function. I suggest you to read about it int the following link https://realpython.com/python-lambda/

Comment: thanks you! i have change the lambda inside a function with provided link and i have change the issue with the type error.